# Establish a new initial view to load prior to loading a current home that now loads an existing IONIC project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Starting from an IONIC project that loads when starting a home view with the initial menu:

Using the typical IONIC home view

```
src \ pages \ home
home.html
home.scss
home.ts
```

Now they want to modify it and add a preview in which a user simply accepts a data policy and then continue to the home view normally.

How should I consider adding this new view with the least impact of changes in the application? The idea is to continue leaving home view because currently in some points of the APP always ends up returning to the home.

It would add a front view of the form

```
src \ pages \ accept
accept.html
accept.scss
accept.ts
```

with a button to accept and continue towards home.

Where to establish in IONIC the name of the view that must load when starting the APP and change its current behavior by default to load home.html?

I'm starting to learn IONIC and I have to make several changes in this APP but this is the one that initially runs the fastest and I'm still not fluent.

Comment: is this ionic v1 or 3?

Comment: It is IONIC V3 because i can see it is using angular 4.  Im sure it isn’t IONIC V1.

Comment: I also suggest you go through some online tutorials before diving into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first module to be loaded when the app starts is app.module.ts which has the page app.component.ts and app.html.

In app.html the root page is loaded using `ion-nav` which handles the navigation stack along with the NavController.

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

You have to change the value set for `rootPage` variable in **app.component.ts**

```
this.rootPage = "AcceptPage"
```

based on any condition you may need to.

Comment: Suraj Rao Thanks for your help. Finding this out on my own would have taken time. I'm going to prove it right now that I have the project in front of me.